# Rstudio gtsummary table with three categorical variables

Tags: gtsummary

I'm trying to figure out how to use the gtsummary package for my dataset.

I have three categorical values and two of those set as strata. I'm not interested in the frequency of each sample but want the numeric value in the table.

Currently I'm using this simple code (x, y, z, are my categorical values, whereas SOC is the numerical values. Y and Z should go in the headline (strata).

```
Data %>%
  select(x, y, z , SOC) %>%
  tbl_strata(strata=z,
             .tbl_fun =
               ~ .x %>%
               tbl_summary(by = y , missing = "no"),
              statistic = list(all_continuous()~ "{mean} ({sd})" ))%>%
  modify_caption("**Soil organic carbon [%]**")%>%
  bold_labels()
```

### Edit

Let's take the trial dataset as an example:

```
trial %>%
  select(trt, grade, stage, age, marker) %>%
  tbl_strata(strata=stage,
             ~tbl_summary(.x, by = grade , missing = "no"),
             statistic = list(all_continuous()~ "{mean} ({sd})" 
))%>%
  bold_labels()
```

What I'm looking for is a table like this, but without the frequency showing of each treatment (Drug A, B). I only want the age and marker to show up in my table but organized by treatment. I'd like to have the first section showing only the age and marker for the group that received Drug A. Then a section showing the same for Drug B.

[image]

### Edit 2

Your input is exactly what I am looking for. With the trial dataset it works perfectly fine. However, ones I put in my data, the numeric values are all in one column instead of in rows. I also still get the frequencies and I can't figure out why. I use exactly the same code and the same amount of variables and my table looks somewhat like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to get in the end. Can you please, 1. Provide a reproducible example we can all run out machines, and 2. Provide an example of what you'd like the final table to look like?

Comment: Thanks you, I edited my initial question

Comment: Apologies, but I am not sure what you're looking for in the end. Can you update with a screenshot of what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks, I added a screenshot of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think nesting calls to `tbl_strata()` (one merging and the other stacking) will get you what you're after. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.5.2'

tbl <- 
  trial %>%
  select(trt, grade, stage, age, marker) %>%
  tbl_strata(
    strata = trt, 
    function(data) {
      data %>%
        tbl_strata(
          strata = stage,
          ~ tbl_summary(
            .x,
            by = grade,
            statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
            missing = "no"
          ) %>%
            modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**")
        )
    },
    .combine_with = "tbl_stack",
    .combine_args = list(group_header = c("Drug A", "Drug B"))
  ) %>% 
  bold_labels()
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2022-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much @Daniel D. Sjoberg Is it possible to add the p-values? Thank you!

Comment: Since it's a nonstandard format, you'd need to add it via 'add_stat()'